# Add extra column to laravel select query

Tags: laravel

It may sound as a duplicate question. Please I have not found a working solution.I want to add additional field to my query in laravel but I am getting error. This is the php implementation

```
select id, "extra_column as type" from cases
```

have tried

```
 DB::table('cases')
         ->select(['id'])
         ->selectSub(function($query){
            $query->selectRaw('extra_column');
           },'type')
           ->get();
```

but I keep getting error

Comment: In the `cases` table, is there a column called `extra_column`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like this:

```
DB::table('cases')
    ->select(['id', 'extra_column as type'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: This generates Unknown column 'extra_column' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Please try `addSelect('extra_column as type')`.

```
DB::table('cases')
     ->select(['id'])
     ->addSelect(`<additional column>`)   // We can able to use variable as well $value = 'extra_column as type';
     ->get();
```

Comment: this returns Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Comment: Could you please confirm the column available in the Table ?

Answer (score 0):

I later found out the solution. the extra_column was missing a double quote

```
DB::table('cases')
         ->select(['id'])
         ->selectSub(function($query){
            $query->selectRaw('"extra_column"');
           },'type')
           ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find that scenario in Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements) like so,

```
$query = DB::table('users')->select('name');
 
$users = $query->addSelect('age')->get();
```

**OR** you can do something like this also:

```
DB::table('users')->select('name')
    ->addSelect('email as user_email');
```

and in case this triggers an issue as you told, please make sure that this column exists in your database.